# Как отправить на свой тестовый url post с json файлом?

Tags: python, requests, url

У меня есть вот этот код на python

```
import requests
import json

data_dict = {}

# Добавление элементов в словарь
data_dict["http://localhost:8080/givedata"] = {"thermostat_id": 1, "temperature_sensor": 20.0, "temperature_weather": 15.0, "wind_speed": 5.0, "temperature_inside": 22.0, "temperature_radiator": 25.0, "current_setpoint": 22.0}
data_dict["http://localhost:8080/api/v1/none"] = {"name": "John", "age": 30}


for data in data_dict:
    print(data)
    # Отправляем POST запрос
    response = requests.post(data, json=data_dict[data])

    # Печатаем ответ от сервера
    print(response.json())
```

Я хочу на свой тестовый url отправить post. Но мне выдает ошибку

```
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8080): 
Max retries exceeded with url: /givedata 
(Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001CF3C1FB4D0>: 
Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061]
Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение'))
```

Код, который слушает post запрос

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.run()


# Отслеживания прихода POST запроса и вызов нейронной сети, для предсказания
@app.route("http://localhost:5000/givedata", methods=["POST"]) # Откуда я получаю post запрос?
def webhook():
    if request.method == "POST":
        dataframe = pd.read_json(request.json)
        predict_nn(dataframe)
```

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148683/discussion-on-question-by-7wafer7------url-post--json); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 0):

Flask стандартно использует порт `5000`.

Попробуйте соответственно тому поправить ключи в вашем словаре, т.е.

```
data_dict["http://localhost:5000/givedata"] = {"thermostat_id": 1, "temperature_sensor": 20.0, "temperature_weather": 15.0, "wind_speed": 5.0, "temperature_inside": 22.0, "temperature_radiator": 25.0, "current_setpoint": 22.0}
data_dict["http://localhost:5000/api/v1/none"] = {"name": "John", "age": 30}
```

Comment: Да стала лучше, спасибо за это. Но теперь при вызове post выдает такую ошибку `127.0.0.1 - - [21/Sep/2023 23:40:38] "POST /givedata HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [21/Sep/2023 23:40:38] "POST /givedata HTTP/1.1" 404 -`

Comment: Я вполне ответил на ваш вопрос, и вам это помогло. Это уже другой вопрос, и потом может быть третий, четвертый... Почему не сначала оценить мой ответ его принятием (клик на галочку налево от него), и затем создать новый?

Comment: Какой хитрый. Потому что на главный вопрос мне не ответили. Я так и не отправил json на url. Я написал, мне это помогло, но проблема не решина

Comment: Пожалуйста, не меняйте ваш вопрос, когда вам на него уже ответили — возникнет путаница для читателей. Ваш вопрос был и есть *«Как отправить на свой тестовый url post с json файлом?»* После моего ответа вы ваш запрос на сервер отправили - сервер вам ответил, хотя ошибкой 404, значит запрос **выл успешно отправлен и принят сервером.** Так что имеет силу мой предыдущий комментарий.

Comment: Ваш код написан правильно. И возможно post запрос был отправлен на этот url, проблема в том, что я не смог проверить, приходит ли json. Потому что выдает ошибку выше.

Comment: @7wafer7 к вопросу отправки клиентом это уже не имеет отношения, это уже про приём сервером

Comment: @andreymal Как я могу проверить правильность его кода, если не смогу увидеть что json пришел

Answer (score 0):

Как указано в это [ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75092269/why-do-i-get-404-not-found-in-flask#:%7E:text=0-,tl%3Bdr%3A%20Works%20great!,-I%20am%20running). Можно воспользоваться таким кодом, что бы отправить post запрос на url

```
import requests
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hello world!"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port="5000")
```

И после отправить вот этот запрос на url

```
data_dict = {
  "thermostat_id": "1",
  "temperature_sensor": "20.0"}

r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000", json=data_dict)
```

Будет выведена вот такая ошибка, но json придет и его можно будет отработать

```
TypeError: The view function for 'webhook' did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2023 15:43:19] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
{'thermostat_id': '1', 'temperature_sensor': '20.0'}
```

Comment: `port="5000"` — ох, всё в той же [документации функции run](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/api/#flask.Flask.run) чётко указано, что `port` должен иметь тип int, а не быть строкой

Comment: А ещё в показанном вами коде нет никакого `get_time` и показанный код в принципе не способен выдать такую ошибку, так что ответ непонятен